# Aligne a tilted polynomial to a set of 3d points

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

So im trying to fit a surface described by a 2 degree polynomial to a set for points in 3d-space. To do this I'm using scipy.optimize curve_fit. The problem is that i cant find a way to allow the curve fit function to adjust the tilt of the function.

My code is rather large so i have added the most important functions for you to see how i have done it so far.

```
def pol2(x, y, *args):
# maybe somehow change this function ? 
    return  args[0] + args[1] * x + args[2] * y + args[3] * x * y + args[4] * x ** 2 + args[5] * y ** 2

def _pol2(M, *args):
    x, y = M
    arr = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for i in range(len(args) // 6):
        arr += pol2(x, y, *args[i * 6:i * 6 + 6])
    return arr


def curve_fit_2d(bd_array,p0):
    # bd_array is a 3d matrix consisting of 0 and 1, where 1 is a boundary voxel
    # p0 is a initial guess i have made a strategy to make this p0 a rather good guess

    tx, ty, tz = bd_arr.nonzero()
    xdata = np.vstack((tx.ravel(), ty.ravel()))
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(_pol2, xdata, tz.ravel(),p0)
    return popt
```

The type of boundary i would like to fit looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfgFB.jpg)

As you can see a tiled 2 degree polynomial looks to be promising. I have tried different strategies, but two problems stops most of them. Curve_fit need a function that only returns the z value (in my case) and if i add to many paramters to curve_fit it is not able to find a fit.

Comment: You must separate the values of `x` and `y` in the function. It will probably be necessary to use `bounds` and `p0`  inside `curve_fit`.

Comment: Why did you pass the second function? You can pass the first function directly to the fit.

Comment: Try to use `def pol2(xy, *args)` and separate `x` and `y` inside the function: `x, y = xy`.